# NTFS file-system sharing control

Tags: software-recommendation, ntfs, share

I have a NTFS partition, and I want to share a folder, but I want to manage the access of the subfolders, for example this folder contains 20 subfolders, the desktop users have access to only 10 subfolders. How can I manage this? How can I control a NTFS partition at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mount the NTFS partition with read-write permissions for root only

```
sudo mount -o fmask=0177,dmask=0077 /dev/sdaX /media/root-view
```

where `/dev/sdaX` is the NTFS partition device, and `/media/root-view` is a mountpoint, to be created if necessary (obviously, you can choose the name you like).

Then install `bindfs` allowing to mount a directory on a mountpoint with modified permissions. The bind mount would be established as follow

```
sudo bindfs -p ugo=rwX /media/root-view/shared /media/user-view
```

where `shared` is a directory you want to share, and `/media/user-view` is another mountpoint, to be created if needed, as above.

Now all users have read-write access to `/media/user-view`, representing the `/shared` folder on the NTFS partition, and no access to other directories on the same partition.

You can repeat the `bindfs` for all directories of your interest, but would be better to reorganize the content of the NTFS partition, putting all directories to share inside a single directory. I mean, change the layout from

```
/shared01
/shared02
...
/shared10
/unshared01
/unshared02
...
/unshared10
```

to

```
/shared
    /shared01
    /shared02
    ...
    /shared10
/unshared
    /unshared01
    /unshared02
    ...
    /unshared10
```

With this layout you only need to share the directory `/shared`, giving automatic access to all sub-directories.